# First time using PC "The computer restarted unexpectedly..." but I have only a wireless keyboard

Tags: windows-10

So, as the title implies I am having trouble booting up my new PC. When I got it, it started, and I tried setting up a wireless keyboard+mouse from inphic. This worked ok, but when I restarted the computer it wasnt recognizing them, so I basically had no way to interact with the computer at all. Instinctively I just powered off hoping that it would fix itself. Oh boy was I wrong. For a long time it was just locked in the booting screen, until I managed to reach a Windows screen telling me that I could re-install windows so I just went for that option. And this is where I ended up with the `"The computer restarted unexpectedly or encountered an unexpected error. Windows installation cannot proceed. To install Windows, click "OK" to restart the computer, then restart the installation"`. However, I cannot use the keyboard to press enter, and when I try with a USB mouse it also doesn't seem to recognize it. Any ideas how can I escape this hell?

Comment: Just checking: at what point did you plug the keyboard receiver into a USB port?

Comment: @simonatrcl I dont remember anymore